# Audience report using the Measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

We have been testing the measurement protocol for a while now to pass Google Analytics information from our servers. We are passing our internal unique user id to `tid/cid` parameters and not the ga's.

Right now it looks like that in our current setup we are not able to generate any Audience reports and I would like to verify my concern that this is due the fact we are passing our own unique userId to the `cid` parameter.

Is it possible to generate Audience reports using the measurement protocol without ga's `cid`?

Answer (score 2):

The way Google Analytics handles Audiences is tying the CID (or UID) with a third party cookie in the doubleclick domain, that is sent using a non-documented parameter of the measurement protocol.

This is only enabled once you turn on [advertiser features](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3450482?hl=en) in the Google Analytics interface. Because you can't access the doubleclick cookies from your server you won't be able to include that in your request.

In other words if your implementation relies solely on the measurement protocol from your server side it won't be possible to have audiences populated. If your implementation includes a mix of web tracking (using the supported client libraries such as gtag.js) and offline using measurement protocol it might be possible to make it work if you are able to use the same Ids on the offline and online tracking methods.

Comment: Just to make sure: this means if we will fetch the client-id using `ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');` and passing it in `cid` parameter we might be able to generate audience report?